# Problem in comparison with Array with type Coordinator

Tags: swift

I have a function called `childDidFinish` that receives a `childCoordinator` with type `Coordinator`, but when I try to compare the parameter received and the element Coordinator inside the Array the error is

> Argument type 'Coordinator' expected to be an instance of a class or class-constrained type

This is my Swift code:

```
private(set) var childCoordinators: [Coordinator] = []

private let navigationController: UINavigationController

init(navigationController: UINavigationController){
    self.navigationController = navigationController
}
func start() {
    let eventListViewController: EventListViewController = .instantiate()
    let eventListViewModel = EventListViewModel()
    
    eventListViewModel.coordinator = self
    eventListViewController.viewModel = eventListViewModel
    navigationController.setViewControllers([eventListViewController], animated: false)
}

func startAddEvent(){
    let addEventCoordinator = AddEventCoordinator(navigationController:navigationController)
    childCoordinators.append(addEventCoordinator)
    addEventCoordinator.start()
}

func childDidFinish(_ childCoordinator: Coordinator){
    
    if let index = childCoordinators.firstIndex(where: { coordinator -> Bool in
        return  childCoordinator === coordinator//There is the problem
    }){
        childCoordinators.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the error message is clear. `===` can be applied only to classes.

Comment: Yeah but what is the best way to compare childCoordinator and a element with type Coordinator inside the childCoordinators for remove it?

Comment: How do I know? You didn't tell me what Coordinator is. But the compiler tells me it isn't a class.

Comment: The coordinator is addEventCoordinator previously added to childCoordinators array.

Comment: Great so you define an unknown by another unknown.

Comment: Is not an Uknown , is a class “AddEventCoordinator” with type Coordinator so for that it’s possible added to a Coordinator array. If you see the method the parameter is type Coordinator, with === I’m comparing two Coordinators class a coordinator class inside the array and the childCoordinator parameter.

Comment: Well it's unknown to _me_ because you didn't show me the declaration of Coordinator or AddEventCoordinator. But you showed them to the compiler, and it says Coordinator is not a class, and I believe the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `Coordinator` is a `protocol`. But in order to be comparable with `===` it must be a class-only protocol, which means it should inherit from `AnyObject` (in recent version of Swift; in earlier Swift versions it had to inherit from `class`)

So all you need to do is add `: AnyObject` to a definition of your protocol:

```
protocol Coordinator: AnyObject {
   // ...
}
```

If this is not the case, then like @matt we need to see your `Coordinator`.

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively make `Coordinator` `Equatable`, whichever it is (protocol, class or struct) and just use `==` instead of `===`